# Why do I get record limit error when the record count is less than the record limit?

Tags: soql, salesforcedx

In VS Code's terminal I execute the following command:

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query --query SELECT COUNT() FROM Lead__c
```

I get the following error:

```
(node:83390) Warning: The query result is missing 46904 records due to a 50000 record limit.
Increase the number of records returned by setting the config value "maxQueryLimit" or the
environment variable "SFDX_MAX_QUERY_LIMIT" to 46904 or greater than 50000.
```

Strictly speaking this is giving me the information I want (there are 46,904 records in the object), but why am I getting this error when the limit is 50,000?

I also tried following the advice and lowering the limit with `sfdx config:set maxQueryLimit=46904` just to see if I could get rid of the warning, but all that did was change the 50,000 in the warning to 46,904.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in the plugin. To avoid the error, try:

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query --query "SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Lead__c"
```